# Exception animating a scale layout transform in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, animation, layouttransform

I have create a storyboard in C# to animation a scale transform on a canvas. The scale transform is a layout transform. Here is my C# code for the animation:

```
Storyboard Configuring = new Storyboard();
if (NexusRoot != null)
{
var current = (NexusRoot.LayoutTransform as ScaleTransform).ScaleX;

Duration duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));

DoubleAnimation myDoubleAnimation1 = new DoubleAnimation();
myDoubleAnimation1.Duration = duration;
Configuring.Children.Add(myDoubleAnimation1);
myDoubleAnimation1.From = current;
myDoubleAnimation1.To = scale;
Storyboard.SetTarget(myDoubleAnimation1, NexusRoot);
Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(myDoubleAnimation1, (PropertyPath)new PropertyPathConverter().ConvertFromString("(UIElement.LayoutTransform).(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)"));

DoubleAnimation myDoubleAnimation2 = new DoubleAnimation();
myDoubleAnimation2.Duration = duration;
Configuring.Children.Add(myDoubleAnimation2);
myDoubleAnimation2.From = current;
myDoubleAnimation2.To = scale;

Storyboard.SetTargetName(myDoubleAnimation2, "NexusRoot");
Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(myDoubleAnimation2, (PropertyPath)new PropertyPathConverter().ConvertFromString("(UIElement.LayoutTransform).(ScaleTransform.ScaleY)"));
}
```

When i run this animation it throws the following exception.

> System.ArgumentNullException was
>   caught   Message="Value cannot be
>   null.\r\nParameter name: dp"
>   Source="WindowsBase"   ParamName="dp" 
>   StackTrace:
>          at System.Windows.DependencyObject.GetValue(DependencyProperty
>   dp)
>          at System.Windows.Media.Animation.Storyboard.ProcessComplexPath(HybridDictionary
>   clockMappings, DependencyObject
>   targetObject, PropertyPath path,
>   AnimationClock animationClock,
>   HandoffBehavior handoffBehavior, Int64
>   layer)
>          at System.Windows.Media.Animation.Storyboard.ClockTreeWalkRecursive(Clock
>   currentClock, DependencyObject
>   containingObject, INameScope
>   nameScope, DependencyObject
>   parentObject, String parentObjectName,
>   PropertyPath parentPropertyPath,
>   HandoffBehavior handoffBehavior,
>   HybridDictionary clockMappings, Int64
>   layer)
>          at System.Windows.Media.Animation.Storyboard.ClockTreeWalkRecursive(Clock
>   currentClock, DependencyObject
>   containingObject, INameScope
>   nameScope, DependencyObject
>   parentObject, String parentObjectName,
>   PropertyPath parentPropertyPath,
>   HandoffBehavior handoffBehavior,
>   HybridDictionary clockMappings, Int64
>   layer)
>          at System.Windows.Media.Animation.Storyboard.BeginCommon(DependencyObject
>   containingObject, INameScope
>   nameScope, HandoffBehavior
>   handoffBehavior, Boolean
>   isControllable, Int64 layer)
>          at System.Windows.Media.Animation.Storyboard.Begin()
>          at StormFront.NexusDesigner.ScaleCanvasAnimation(Double
>   scale) in C:\Documents and
>   Settings\lbeaver\Desktop\StormFront\WPF\StormFront\StormFront\NexusDesigner.xaml.cs:line
>   544   InnerException:

How do i stop this exception from happening?

Comment: Could you please format your text better? The stack trace is not readable

Comment: `NexusDesigner.xaml.cs:line 544`  Line 554?  Kill me now.

Comment: The stack trace isnt helpful any way. As you can see the source of the exception is WindowsBase and not in my code.

Comment: Also the line 554 is when the storyboard.begin is called

Answer (score 3):

I found my problem. The problem is in the property path. I was using UIElement and should have been using FrameworkElement.

So this line:

```
Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(myDoubleAnimation1, (PropertyPath)new PropertyPathConverter().ConvertFromString("(UIElement.LayoutTransform).(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)"));
```

should be:

```
Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(myDoubleAnimation1, (PropertyPath)new PropertyPathConverter().ConvertFromString("(FrameworkElement.LayoutTransform).(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)"));
```